# Python Basic Auth

Tags: python, basic-authentication

Attempting to follow [this tutorial on basic auth](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml#introduction) - this ends up being the final example:

```
import urllib2

theurl = 'http://www.someserver.com/toplevelurl/somepage.htm'
username = 'johnny'
password = 'XXXXXX'
# a great password

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
# this creates a password manager
passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)
# because we have put None at the start it will always
# use this username/password combination for  urls
# for which `theurl` is a super-url

authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
# create the AuthHandler

opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# All calls to urllib2.urlopen will now use our handler
# Make sure not to include the protocol in with the URL, or
# HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm will be very confused.
# You must (of course) use it when fetching the page though.

pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(theurl)
# authentication is now handled automatically for us
```

If I take this and enter my own values for theurl, username and pw and attempt to run the script it doesn't do anything non of the variables seem to get substituted... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What values are you substituting....

Comment: I'm taking theurl, username, and password at the top and swapping in my actual info.... 

maybe it is actually doing something yet I need a way to print out the output?